# CoffeeScript Invalid Syntax :

Tags: javascript, syntax, coffeescript, syntax-error, node-modules

I have updated my coffescript module from 1.6.3 to 1.7.1 and now my code will no longer compile. What is the proper syntax for this? I believe it is to replace : with =.

Console Error:

```
password: 'test',
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Complete snap of code section

```
module.exports =  
 mongo_url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/testmaker_api_testing?poolSize=5"
 mock_s2:
  mac_id: "mocks2_MD"
  password: "!ensandbox1"
  domain: "talkrnd.testmaker.net"
  prod_mac_id: "mocks2_prod"
  prod_password: "!mocks21"

route_prefix: "/testmaker/v1"
user:
  userName: 'monkey',
  password: 'test',
  email: 'monkey@testmaker.com',
  fullName: 'Monkey Nackles'
  admin: true
  groups : ['Admin']

op_user:
  userName: 'booz',
  password: 'test',
  email: 'BBla@testmaker.com',
  fullName: 'Booz Bla'
  admin: false
  groups : ['op']

killable_user:
  userName: 'I will die',
  password: 'pass',
  email: 'nocener@testmaker.com',
  fullName: 'John Doe'
  admin: false
  groups : ['']
```

This is my config file. When I complied with coffee-script 1.7.1 I was getting an error with my mongo_url line to change ":" and I changed it to "=" and the error went away but then the next error occurred at the 13th line for password. Again for "=". I do not believe this is an error with just the syntax.

Thank you in advance

Comment: We need a lot more context to understand what that code is meant to represent. Is it an object initializer, or what?

Comment: Could you enlarge your snapshot?

Comment: This question cannot be answered: This is [valid coffee-script](http://goo.gl/9myUXe), so the error must be somewhere else in your code. (http://goo.gl/9myUXe)

Comment: [This](http://goo.gl/2bVtnj) is what you have. Is [this](http://goo.gl/kYyEzS) what you want? You have bad indentation then.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing comma after your dictionary values, e.g. *username: 'monkey',* should be *username: 'monkey'*.

That said, your code *does* compile with CoffeeScript 1.7.1. Maybe there's a whitespace issue or something. Try copying the code from your question and compile it yourself.

Comment: If that was the case aknuds1 why I am getting an issue with the second line. 

    mongo_url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/testmaker_api_testing?poolSize=5" Error Message: mongo_url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/powertalk_api_testing?poolSize=5" ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: @TheAce Well, like I said, even though the extraneous commas may be stylistically problematic, your code does actually compile with CoffeeScript 1.7.1, as I have tried myself. Please follow my suggestion and copy the code from your question to the file test.coffee, and compile it with `coffee -c test.coffee`. You should see that it compiles without problems.